# How to add a sectionGroup into web.config programmatically

Tags: c#, app-config

**Background**

I want to insert the following into my web.config

```
  <sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
  </sectionGroup>
```

(no prizes for guessing what I am trying to achieve!) but I am getting thoroughly confused.  The docs on MSDN suggest that I need to create a subclass of ConfurationSection if I want to add one to a group.  I wrote myself a little windows application to help me figure it out but I did not get very far!  Here is the pertinent code - which tries to add the just the "security" section.

```
private void AddElmahSectionGroup()
{
    string exePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "NameOfExe.exe");
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);

    ConfigurationSectionGroup elmahGroup = configuration.GetSectionGroup(elmahSectionGroupName);
    if (elmahGroup != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sectionGroup with name {0} already in web.config", elmahSectionGroupName);
        return;
    }
    elmahGroup = new ConfigurationSectionGroup();
    configuration.SectionGroups.Add(elmahSectionGroupName, elmahGroup);

    var securitySection = new Section { Name = "security", RequirePermission = false, Type = "Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" };
    elmahGroup.Sections.Add("security", securitySection);

    configuration.Save();
}

public class Section : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get { return (String)this["name"]; } set { this["name"] = value; } }

    [ConfigurationProperty("requirePermission", IsRequired = true)]
    public bool RequirePermission { get { return (bool)this["requirePermission"]; } set { this["requirePermission"] = value; } }

    [ConfigurationProperty("type", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Type { get { return (string)this["type"]; } set { this["type"] = value; } }
}
```

And here is the resultant configuration file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="elmah" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionGroup, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" >
            <section name="security" type="ConfigEditing.Form1+ElmahLogic+Section, ConfigEditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <elmah>
        <security name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </elmah>
</configuration>
```

Which completely twisted my melon: -

- first of all the `type` of the `section` element is the type of my class (derived from ConfigurationSection)
- second by adding a sectionGroup definition into the group, I (at the same time) adding the group into the config.

I am not really surprised by these findings because I really don't understand the API but I just have not found any decent docs about what I want to do.  Can anyone here help - even if it just pointing me at an MSDN example that is an actual full working example.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example that will add a section like the following to app.config:

```
//<configSections>
//  <sectionGroup name="elmah" type="Overflow.CustomConfigurationSectionGroup, Overflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" >
//  </sectionGroup>
//</configSections>

namespace Overflow
{
    public class CustomSecuritySection : ConfigurationSection
    {
    }

    public class CustomConfigurationSectionGroup : ConfigurationSectionGroup
    {
        public CustomConfigurationSectionGroup()
        {
            Security = new CustomSecuritySection();
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("security")] 
        public CustomSecuritySection Security { get; private set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, Application.ProductName + ".exe"));

            config.SectionGroups.Add("elmah", new CustomConfigurationSectionGroup());

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it does not add anything more than my example code (except your example does not do anything with the security group that you create).

Comment: I thought that was the question: how to add just a configSection to app.config: 'I want to insert the following into my web.config'.